# Accessing the isolate scope of a compiled directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am compiling a directive successfully using the following code:

```
var element, $injector, $compile, link, scope;

element = angular.element(document.getElementById(#whatever));
$injector = element.injector();
$compile = $injector.get('$compile');
link = $compile(angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>'));

scope = element.scope();
scope.foo = 'foo'; // I want to place this on the isolate scope!
element.append(link(scope));
```

The directive has an isolate scope. The `scope` variable above gives me the scope for the parent element. How can I get the isolate scope for the directive?

Comment: Have you tried `angular.element(link(scope)).isolateScope()`

Comment: Thanks that works. Please add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular `element` object has some predefined functions such as `isolatedScope`. The challenge is to call it on the right element. Something like this works:

`angular.element(link(scope)).isolateScope()`

Here you get hold of the compiled+linked html fragment for the directive and then call the `isolatedScope()` function to get the isolated scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use `link(scope).isolateScope()` to get the compiled element's isolated scope